# Dockerで立ち上げたWebサービスの為のポートの開放が出来ないです。

Tags: docker

現在、Dockerを用いてWebサービスを試しに利用しようとしております。試しにWindows10 PCで

```
docker run -d -p <外部からアクセスされるポート番号>:<コンテナ側のポート番号> -t -i -h <コンテナ名> --name <コンテナを指定する名前>
```

として幾つかWebサービスを導入しました。自分のPCの場合特にポートを指定せずに導入したサービスは"http://localhost/"にアクセスする事で利用できたのですが、下の図にある通り、8000番に立ち上げたWebサービス(ここではJenkins)[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]に関してはエラーメッセージが表示されてしまい、アクセスする事ができませんでした。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ファイアウォールは無効にしているのですが、他に利用できる様にするのに必要な設定があるのかご存知の方は教えて頂けないでしょうか？

Yuki Inoue さんに対する返信：
jenkinsを再度入れ直して、STATUSを見た所、今回は立ち上がっている様でした。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

その後再度アクセスしたのですが結果は同じでした...
ログ(末尾)は以下の様になっていました。導入は上手く行っている様ですが、その後のアクセスに関するログは見られませんでした。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ポートは関係なく、 STATUS が Exited とあるので、サーバーは異常終了しています。 docker logs jenkins で何か表示されますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins は、[公式のjenkins](https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins/)でしょうか。 how to use によると、

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 jenkins
```

と書いてあるので、 8080 番のポートを開けてそこにアクセスする必要があるのではと考えています。

上記ポートで試すとどうなるでしょうか？

---

追記: ホスト側で 8000 ポートで待ち受けたい場合は、ポート指定のオプションを `-p 8000:8080` に変えれば実現できます。

Comment: 返信遅くなり申し訳ありません。一度jenkinsのImageを削除した後に、ご紹介頂いたコマンドで試した所、8080のポートにはJenkinsのログイン画面が、50000のポートにはバージョン情報が表示されるのを確認出来ました。ただ、再度8080を8000に置き換えてImageを入れてみたのですが、その場合には再度エラーが出てしまいました。ポートの解放の設定が不適切な様なので、その原因を調査してみます。

Comment: @nobelnambu コンテナ側のポートは、 8080 で立ち上がっていて、そこれはおそらく固定です。 docker ホスト側で、 8000 ポートで待ち受けて、そこから jenkins コンテナのログイン画面を表示したい、ということでしょうか？

Comment: ご指摘の通りです。目的としてはDockerで複数のWebサービスを同時に立ち上げられる様に異なるポートを割り当てる事を考えていました。

Comment: @nobelnambu `-p 8000:8080` でホスト側は 8000 に割り当てられると思っていますが、どうでしょう？

Comment: アドバイス通り-p 8000:8080を実行した所上手く行きました! アドバイスありがとうございます。ご存知だったら教えて欲しいのですが、Dockerではコンテナ側のポートを8080以外には出来ないのでしょうか？個人的にはあるWebサービス1は8000番、Webサービス2は8001番などとDockerで立ち上げて利用したいと考えて居たのですが...

Comment: @nobelnambu それを行うことのメリットは、ないのではないかと思います。というのも、 docker の中のポートが何になっているかは、基本的に docker の -p などの設定によって、あまり関係がなくなるからです。一応、 [公式ドキュメント](https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins/) を眺めていると、 `JENKINS_OPTS` に `--httpPort=8000` などやるとコンテナ内でのポートは変えられそうではありますが。

Comment: 丁寧にご教示ありがとうございました。幾つかのWebサービスを気軽にDockerで利用したいという目的は達成できそうです。お陰様で目処がたちましたので、本件はこれで解決とし、より詳細を理解する必要がある時は公式ドキュメントにも目を通す様に致しますm(_ _)m